# Insert a char (e.g. tab) at the beginning of a row, if the row contains an other char: notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to insert a char at he beginning of a row, but only if the specific row contains a symbol.

E.g. add `\t` at the beginning of a row, if the row contains at least one `;` symbol

I have searched for the regex feature, so obviously I'm able to add a `\t` at the beginning of each row, but not able to insert the condition only if the row is containing a symbol with regex

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*;)`
- Replace with: `\t`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?=           # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    ;           # semicolon
  )             # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]